# Vue - How to use Getter / Setting in v-model with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Some reason my `getter` is not pulling in the data from my Vuex Store when I use a getter / setter in my `v-for` loop. I'm not getting any errors, the data just isn't being pulled in like it should.

Here is my code.

My v-for loop (truncated)

```html
   <template
      v-for="(detail,index) in details"
    >
      <v-row
        :key="detail.title"
      >
        <v-col
          cols="12"
        >
          <v-textarea
            solo
            auto-grow
            flat
            :placeholder="detail.placeholder"
            v-model="detail.model"
            rows="2"
            row-height="10px"
          ></v-textarea>
         </v-col>
        </v-row>
     </template>
```

My data element `details` where the loop is coming from:

```js
  details: [
    {
      title: "DESCRIBE YOUR BRIDAL GOWN: WHO DESIGNED IT? WHAT STYLE?", 
      placeholder: "include your details here", 
      model: "gown", 
      showDivider: true 
    },
    {
      title: "WHERE’S YOUR WEDDING? INCLUDE LOCATION DETAILS (E.G., ADDRESS, TYPE, DESTINATION)", 
      placeholder: "include your details here", 
      model: "weddingLocation", 
      showDivider: true 
    },
    {
      title: "WHAT DO YOU WANT YOUR BRIDESMAIDS TO WEAR? THINK PINTEREST BOARDS, NECKLINES, COLORS, AND LENGTH.", 
      placeholder: "include your details here", 
      model: "theme", 
      showDivider: false 
    },
  ]
```

Then finally my getters / setters. By themselves, outside the for loop, they work fine. So its not the store or the getters/setter but somehow the interaction between the loop and those computed properties:

```js
computed: {
...mapGetters('wedding', [
  'returnWedding',
]),
date: {
  get() {
    let day = this.returnWedding.day > 9 ? '' + this.returnWedding.day : '0' + this.returnWedding.day
    let month = this.returnWedding.month > 9 ? '' + this.returnWedding.month : '0' + this.returnWedding.month
    let year = this.returnWedding.year
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day
  },
  set(value) {
    this.updateLocalWedding({ bridalGown: value })
  }
},
gown: {
  get() {
    return this.returnWedding.bridalGown
  },
  set(value) {
    this.updateLocalWedding({ bridalGown: value })
  }      
},
weddingLocation: {
  get() {
    return this.returnWedding.locationDetails
  },
  set(value) {
    this.updateLocalWedding({ locationDetails: value })
  }
},
theme: {
  get() {
    return this.returnWedding.theme
  },
  set(value) {
    this.updateLocalWedding({ theme: value })
  }
},
}
```

Comment: Can't see anywhere where you're using your computed properties

Comment: If you look at the `details` array it has a `model` field in it. Those are the names of the getters/setters that are then put into the `v-model` field by `v-for`

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. The only thing `v-model="detail.model"` does is allow you to set the string value of the `model` property. This has absolutely nothing to do with your computed properties. To use those, you'd need something like `v-model="gown"`, `v-model="weddingLocation"`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't directly possible.

You'd need something like this

```html
<v-textarea v-model="thisVueInstance[detail.model]" />
```

in order to reference the computed properties by name. The problem is, you can't reference the current Vue instance in the template like that. Neither of these options work

```html
<v-textarea v-model="this[detail.model]" />
<v-textarea v-model="[detail.model]" />
```

---

What I've found does work is to set up a computed property to return the current Vue instance, eg

```js
computed: {
  // ...
  form: vm => vm
}
```

Then use this in your template as the object reference base

```html
<v-textarea v-model="form[detail.model]" />
```